# Ring of regular functions on a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety. Then the ring $\mathcal{O}_X$ of regular functions on $X$ is $A(X) := k[y_1,\dots,y_n] / I_X$, where $I_X$ is the vanishing ideal of $X$ (and $k$ is algebraically closed). Now let us apply this definition to $X=\left\{p\right\}$, the affine variety of a single point. Since the vanishing ideal $m_p$ of $p$ is maximal, we get that $\mathcal{O}_p = k$. But this contradicts direct application of the definition "regular", according to which $\mathcal{O}_p$ is the set of quotients $g/h$ of polynomials such that $h(p) \neq 0$, i.e. $(k[y_1,\dots,y_n])_{m_p}$. What am i missing here?

**Edit I:** My confusion comes from applying the definition of a regular function $f$ on the point $p$ of the variety $\left\{p\right\}$. By definition there must exist a neighborhood of $p$ such that $f$ can be written as the quotient $f=g/h$, where $h$ does not vanish anywhere on this neighborhood. The only possible neighborhood is $p$ and so this gives that any regular function must be of the form $f=g/h, h(p) \neq 0$.

**Edit II:** In summary, applying the definition of regular function on the variety $X=\left\{p\right\}$ yields $\mathcal{O}_X = (k[y_1,\dots,y_n])_{m_p}$, while applying the characterization $\mathcal{O}_X = k[y_1,\dots,y_n]/I_X$ yields $\mathcal{O}_X=k$. Certainly $(k[y_1,\dots,y_n])_{m_p} \neq k$. The point that i was missing (thanks to Hoot and Zev) is that these two rings coincide if we view them as functions on $p$. And to do that we simply have to take the quotient of $(k[y_1,\dots,y_n])_{m_p}$ by $m_p$.

Comment: Your definition of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ doesn't seem to depend on $X$ at all. Surely it's not correct.

Comment: @Hoot: I didn't define anywhere $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. I am just working through the definition of regular functions applied on a single point.

Comment: I wrote $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}$ to emphasize the role of $X$. What you wrote down for $\mathcal{O}_p$ is the definition of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n, p}$. I don't see why you would expect this to interact well with $A(X)$ which depends on the variety $X$. $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}$ should be the quotient of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n, p}$ by the ideal $I(X)\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n, p}$ and indeed this is the case here. One should also be able to compute this by localizing $A(X)$ at the appropriate maximal ideal and indeed this works too -- localization and taking quotients "commute".

Comment: @Hoot: I edited to explain my point of confusion.

Comment: Your new definition (I do think it's different) is a little better. These are the same ring, then. Different expressions $g/h$ give the same *function*, that's all. Any expression like $g/h$ that you write determines a function $\{p\} \to k$ sending $p$ to $g(p)/h(p)$. These correspond to the elements of $k$.

Comment: It is not. Read all of I.3 of Hartshorne for proper definitions. Sure it's a scary book but at least he makes these things precise. Whatever you're reading (Harris?) doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Hoot: I finally think i understand: if we view the two rings $k$ and $(k[y_1,\dots,y_n])_{m_p}$ as functions on the variety $\left\{p\right\}$ then they coincide. How do that formally? Simply take the quotient by $I_X=m_p$. Aha!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing up two very different things.

The **coordinate ring** of a variety $X$ with vanishing ideal $I$ is
$$k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]/I$$
which represents the ***regular*** *functions* ***on the variety*** *$X$*. If $X$ is a point $\{p\}$, the ring of regular functions on the set $\{p\}$ to the field $k$ is equal to the ring of polynomials $k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]$, modulo the equivalence relation of *"defining the same function on $\{p\}$"*, which produces $k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]/I$.

(Also, just intuitively,  the collection of functions $\{p\}\to k$ is clearly going to be isomorphic to $k$.)

The **local ring** of an (irreducible) variety $X$ with vanishing ideal $I$ is
$$k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]_{I}$$
which represents the ***rational*** *functions on $k^n$ that* ***don't blow up*** *on $X$*. If $X$ is a point $\{p\}$, the ideal of regular functions on $k^n$ that vanish on $\{p\}$ is $I$, so the ring of ***rational*** functions on $k^n$ that don't blow up on $I$ is the collection of $\frac{f}{g}$ where $f\in k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ and $g\in k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]\setminus I$, which produces
$k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]_{I}$.

So there's no contradiction.

Comment: Dear Zev, i think the answer to my question is the very first answer you had written. But i enjoyed this answer too since it clarified for the notion of local ring of a variety. So i am upvoting it.